# Are Javascript Instagram applications that authenticate with client_id allowed?

Tags: javascript, instagram

A few web-based applications I maintain have been using JavaScript on the page to fetch posts from Instagram* through their API, only authenticating with a `client_id`. With the Instagram API changes recently (applications are sandboxed until approved) this no longer works.

Is this kind of application allowed by Instagram? Or is it considered a security risk to expose the `client_id` in the Javascript that performs the request? If it matters, the application is for internal use by a few employees only.

---

* Specifically, the 10 last posts from a fixed user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All instagram API endpoints now require a valid `access_token` rather than `client_id`. The search endpoint is an example of one that didn't previously require an `access_token`. You can find this in the [Change logs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/)

> All API endpoints require a valid access_token
>   All API endpoints require a specific permission scope granted by the user

You can authorise your own account and grab the last 20 posts, but for any more than that you will need to submit your app for review

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new app.. My app was deleted instead of going to sandbox mode.

As you need 10 last posts, this should work on sandbox mode.

> **Content Display for Personal Website**. If you are a developer and you want to showcase Instagram content on a website, then you do not need to submit your app for review. By using a client in sandbox mode, you will still be able to access the last 20 media of any sandbox user that grants you permission.